# Me elimina el ultimo registro

Tags: vue.js, vuetify, dialog

Tengo el problema que al presionar en el boton eliminar me elimina el ultimo registro de la tabla, no me elimina el que selecciono, pero eso me pasa cuando uso el dialog de vuetify, cuando uso solo el confirm de windows si me elimina correctamente..aqui el codigo html

```
<v-dialog
                                v-model="dialog"
                                persistent
                                width="500px"
                                >  
                                <v-card>
                                    <v-card-title 
                                        class="text-h5">
                                        Desea eliminar el registro¡¡
                                    </v-card-title>                           
                                    <v-card-text>    
                                    </v-card-text>  
                                    <v-card-actions>
                                        <v-spacer></v-spacer>            
                                        <v-btn
                                            color="green-darken-1"
                                            variant="text"
                                            @click="dialog = false"
                                            >Cancel
                                        </v-btn>

                                        <v-btn
                                            color="green-darken-1"
                                            variant="text"
                                            @click="dialog = eliminar(dat.id)"
                                            >OK
                                        </v-btn>
                                    </v-card-actions>
                                </v-card>
                            </v-dialog>
                            <v-btn 
                                class="elevation-5 bg-blue-grey-darken-2 rounded-lg btn_editar" 
                                @click="mostrar_dialog()"
                                >Eliminar
                            </v-btn>
```

Al hacer click en 'ok' llamo a la funcion eliminar que recibe el id, el dialog le digo que es false para que no se muestre, luego cuando hago click en el boton eliminar llamo a la funcion mostrar_dialog

```
const mostrar_dialog=()=>{
        dialog.value = true
    }
    const eliminar=(id:any)=>{
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("id", id);

            axios.post("http://localhost:8888/eliminar/",formData)
            .then((response)=>{
                let r = response.data   
                console.log(r)
                if(r.status=="OK"){
                    console.log(r.message+" "+r.datos) 
                }
                dato.value = r.datos
                obtener()
            }).catch((error)=>{
                console.log(error)
            })    
        }
```